# Load balancing and HA with Nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, high-availability

*Preface: I'm trying to implement Blue-Green Deployment.*

With the following `nginx.conf`:

```
http {

    upstream backend {
        keepalive_timeout               65;

        server django_blue:8000 fail_timeout=5s max_fails=1;
        server django_green:8000 fail_timeout=5s max_fails=1;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        location / {
            proxy_pass              http://backend;
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_read_timeout      2s;
            client_max_body_size    20m;
        }
    }
}
```

- If `django_blue` and `django_green` are both up & running all is working well: nginx does correctly LB in Roundrobin.
- If I shutdown one of them - say `django_green` and then go on Chrome to do a web request, if the round robin gives the shutted down server, `django_green`, it waits for 1 minute (exactly 60 secs) and then reply to the browser with `504 Gateway Error`.

So I've two questions:

1. why it waits 1 mins and not `fail_timeout` value?
2. why it don't simply reply with the another available server in `upstream` directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, that's a `proxy_connect_timeout` issue.

So I've just added:
`proxy_connect_timeout   2s;`

to `location / {}` block

Comment: Make sure to mark this as the accepted answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: Check out nginxconfig.io for all of your future config needs.